# Get ASP.NET Identity users by role

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I created a new MVC project with ASP.NET Identity as my authentication and authorization framework, using the individual authentication method. I successfully added 3 roles to the application: `Admin`, `Customer`, `Owner`.

Now I've made three action methods in my `HomeController`: "All Admins", "All Customers", "All Owners". How can I, in each action method, display the users that are in each role and their total count? Meaning when I click on "All Admins" it display all users with admin roles, and the same with the "All Customers" and "All Owners" actions.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. Your second question is a bit broad and could use some more information and code. Ask a new question for that.

Comment: Point 1 s more like information, I think it should be like question.

Comment: @CodeCaster, your edit removes part of the OP's original question - "I want to display the **total numbers** and information of selected Action" - he wants the total number of users as well, that's why I included it in my edit.

Comment: @enki.dev yeah and your edit should not have been approved in my opinion, as it removed way too much of the original meaning. However after that, the attention seemed to lie in obtaining the count, while OP originally stated they want to display the users. Counting records that you have already queried is trivial with Linq.

Comment: @CodeCaster, "removed to much of the original meaning" I think I'll have to disagree with you on that one..

Comment: @CodeCaster, Either way, the question is a lot easier to read and will likely get more attention.   I am curious as to why you feel I removed to much from the post, that was not my intention, I thought I had kept it pretty much in line with the OPs question, just a bit more readable..

Comment: @samira [OP already did](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33197402/link-asp-net-identity-users-to-user-detail-table/33197562#33197562).

Comment: @enki.dev see the current revision of the question, in which I re-added most of the original text.

Comment: @CodeCaster, Got it. It does look better. I appreciate the feedback, just trying to do my part around here - will try to do better next time.

Comment: @enki.dev no problem, happy to help. You _did_ make it more readable, you just removed too much in my opinion. :)

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `RoleManager` and `UserManager`. The latter lets you query on RoleId only, so you'll have to look up the Role first:

```
// Look up the role
string roleName = "Admin";
var role = await _roleManager.Roles.SingleAsync(r => r.Name == roleName);

// Find the users in that role
var roleUsers = _userManager.Users.Where(u => u.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId == role.Id));
```

Now you can send the `roleUsers` to a view that displays the users and their total count.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem so I used something like this:

```
var administrators = from role in _roleManager.Roles
    from userRoles in role.Users
    join user in _userManager.Users on userRoles.UserId equals user.Id
    where role.Name == "Administrator"
    select new UserVm()
    {
        Id = user.Id,
        FirstName = user.FirstName,
        LastName = user.LastName,
        Email = user.Email,
        Role = role.Name
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

I could not find the `SingleAsync` method of the `RoleManager` as described by 
CodeCaster.

So there is another way to get the role by name:

```
        string roleName = "Employee";

        var role = await RoleManager.FindByNameAsync(roleName);
```

and then get the users:

```
    var users  = UserManager.Users.Where(x=>x.Roles.Any(y=>y.RoleId==role.Id))
                    .Select(x => new {UserId = x.Id,FullName = x.FullName });
```