# Link ASP.NET Identity users to user detail table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've used default MVC template with individual authorization. After running the application it automatically creates the required Identity tables. I've successfully registered a few users and all of them are stored in the `AspNetUser` table.

Now what I want is the logged in user can add more information like first name, last name, address etc. For this I've created another table `PersonalInformation` with columns to store this information.

I've also created an `EditProfile` Action in the `ManageController`.

Now how can I link the ASP.NET Identity user to this table? Should I add an `Id` column as a foreign key to `AspNetUser`? Also how can I successfully store the edited information in "PersonalInformation" table along with the logged in user id?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create one to one relationship between user and personal information and then create or update user using Application User Manager.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }

    public virtual PersonalInformation PersonalInformation { get; set; }
}

public class PersonalInformation 
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("User")]
    public string UserId { get;set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    // other fields...

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get;set; }
}


// Create user      
var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
var manager =  new ApplicationUserManager(store);
var user = new ApplicationUser() { Email = "email@email.com", UserName = "username", PersonalInformation = new PersonalInformation { FirstName = "FirstName" } };
manager.Create(user, "Password123!");

// Update user
var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
var manager =  new ApplicationUserManager(store);
var user = manager.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == id);
user.PersonalInformation.FirstName = "EditedName";
manager.Update(user);
```

Comment: Hi I am also new to MVC. I am trying to do something similar to the question above. I have created my link table and now I'm trying to use code like your example to store data but can't figure where to put it. Where do I enter this code to do so?

Comment: Edin in my scenario, I want to add the personalinformation first and then the id in personalinformation should become the id in user

Comment: I tried doing like this, but it throws me following exception: `Member_AspUser_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Member_AspUser_Source' in relationship 'Member_AspUser'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.`  Is there anything missing ?

Answer (score 0):

The way identity interfaces with the database is automatic via the entity framework. In your solution there should be a class called ApplicationDbContext, this is the entity framework context. Personally i would suggest looking up some entity framework guides and work out how it interacts with identity. but a quick overview would be :

To add another table to your database with entity framework you would need to add a DbSet into the context.

```
public DbSet<PersonalInformation> personalInformation {get;set;}
```

Then you would need to update the ApplicationUser to hold a reference to a personalInforamtion.
Then you would need to migrate the database to the latest version, either with a generated migration or with automatic migrations.

Any changes you would then do would be through the entity framework.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should add a foreign key to your table. How to do so depends on how you set up your Entity Framework (EDMX / code first / reverse engineered from database), but this proceduree is explained in plenty other questions. That is a separate question and that has been answered before, try searching.

Now to store the details for a user, you can either create a record in your `PersonalInformation` table upon registering this user, or checking if it exists when editing a user:

```
var currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

// Look up existing record
var personalInformation = _dbContext.PersonalInformation
                                    .FirstOrDefault(p => p.UserId == currentUserId);

if (personalInformation == null)
{
    // If not exists, create and attach new record
    personalInformation = _dbContext.PersonalInformation.Create();  
}

// Map incoming model properties to entity

personalInformation.FirstName = model.FirstName;
personalInformation.Address = model.Address;

// ...

// Add or update the entity in the database
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
                var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext());
                var ctx = store.Context;
                var currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext());
var ctx = store.Context;
var currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());  
pedido.Nombre = currentUser.Nombre;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation how the above code solves the problem.

Comment: What do not you understand? I put on duty as reference the fields aspNetUser