# Link ASP.Net Identity table to a user detail table

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I am trying to link my Identity user table to a user detail table I have created to track other user information. That user detail table is called UserProfile.

I came across this link but it is not working in .NET Core 2.1:
[Link ASP.NET Identity users to user detail table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33197402/link-asp-net-identity-users-to-user-detail-table)

Here is what I have currently:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{

    [Key]
    public override string Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }

}

[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("User")]
    public string UserId { get; set; } // UserId (Primary key) 
    public string UserName { get; set; } // UserName 
    public string FirstName { get; set; } // FirstName
    public string LastName { get; set; } // LastName

    //[ForeignKey("Id")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

However, elsewhere in the code I call:

```
var user = await _userMgr.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);
```

And user.UserProfile is null.

I have tried many combinations of data annotations and even fluent api to no avail.

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
       .HasOne(c => c.UserProfile)
       .WithOne(t => t.User)
       .HasForeignKey<UserProfile>(b => b.UserId);
```

I also tried turning on lazy loading but that couldn't even load the property.

Does anyone know how to do this in .Net Core 2.1?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your main issue is simply that `UserManager` has no functionality to include related entities, such as your `UserProfile`. As a result, you have two options:

1. Use your context directly instead. Then you can eagerly load your `UserProfile` along with the `ApplicationUser` instance, in just one query to the database:

   ```
   var user = await _context.Users.Include(x => x.UserProfile).SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UserName ==  model.UserName);
   ```
2. You can explicitly load the related `UserProfile` instead. This will result in an extra query, though, for a total of two: one to get the user and one to get the related profile:

   ```
   await _context.Entry(user).Reference(x => x.UserProfile).LoadAsync();
   ```

However, frankly, you should not have `UserProfile` at all. ASP.NET Identity is not like ASP.NET Membership. With the latter, you had to have a separate `UserProfile` because the "user" in Membership was not extensible. In Identity, the user *is* extensible, so if you want additional profile information on it, just add it to the class:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; } // FirstName
    public string LastName { get; set; } // LastName
}
```

Note that I trimmed a lot of cruft here as well. There's no point in overriding the `Id` and then leaving it auto-implemented. Additionally, you obviously don't need the `UserName` property from `UserProfile` because `IdentityUser` already has that, which then of course means your `ApplicationUser` has it as well.

**UPDATE**

How the user data is persisted doesn't have to affect whether it can be a claim or not. In other words, you don't have to literally save data as claim in order to access it as claim. Just derive from `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser>`, override `CreateAsync`, and then register it with service collection as scoped.

```
public class MyClaimsPrincipalFactory : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>
{
    public MyClaimsPrincipalFactory(UserManager<TUser> userManager, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor)
        : base(userManager, optionsAccessor)
    {
    }

    public async override Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        var principal = await base.CreateAsync(user);
        ((ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity).AddClaims(new[]
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.FirstName),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, user.LastName),
            // etc.
        });

        return principal;
    }
}
```

Then in `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>, MyClaimsPrincipalFactory>();
```

Comment: Is option 1 the same thing as this: await _userMgr.Users.Include(x => x.UserProfile).SingleAsync(x => x.UserName == model.UserName); where _userMgr is the current UserManager?

Comment: No. `UserManager` is a wrapper around your context to make certain things in Identity easier. It is not a replacement for your context. It does only what it needs to.

Comment: @chris, how to achieve same in database first approach?

Comment: @Sangeeta: None of this is specific to a code-first approach, and none of it would be affected by using an existing database instead. Not sure what you're asking.

Comment: It is using EF and the relationship is defined, so I think this is strange, unexpected, and lacking.  However, this behavior was confirmed here: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/724 , so I guess we really have to this way.

Comment: @YahooSerious: Not really. In EF, relationships are *never* automatically loaded. You always must either eagerly, explicitly or lazy load. Lazy loading would be the closest to "automatic", but there's still a separate query, making it no better than explicitly loading in this regard. The chief issue is that UserManager provides no ability to eager load with Include, but it also doesn't need to. That's no what it's for, and again, you shouldn't have a separate profile relationship you would need to load, anyways.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I did not know whether to expect lazy or eager, but did expect some loading or an exception, not a 'plain' null.
I did add 'plain' properties to `AspNetUsers` (but can imagine people wanting to keep their extensions separate in a parallel one-to-one table).
However I want a one-to-many relationship (e.g. a preferred-language, preferred-valuta combo per country - {"Poland", "English", "Zloty"}).  The properties will probably be gathered into a json-structure when generating claims.  But I prefer separate realtionships for easier querying, understanding and maintenance.

Comment: It also depends on the context you're working in. In most cases, where you're querying a user, it should really just be to create or update it. For reads, you should really be using the principal, as that's the only consistency across distributed systems. In that regard, whether it be simple props, relationships, etc., they should be added as claims when the principal is created, and that's what you should pull from. Now, of course, that doesn't apply to every relationship, but it does apply to things you always need, versus just sometimes.

Comment: I think you are right, and will put the json in claims.  As I kept coming across contradicting examples and considerations, and I could not find a 'guideline', I tried to phrase a rule of thumb [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57146798). Is that also what you mean?

Comment: You can opt to store data literally as claims or you can simply map data *to* claims. Personally for most user data, I prefer to actually keep them as typed database columns and then just propagate to claims when the principal is being created. I'll update my answer with some more info.